# Apache thrift compiler build error by Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, thrift, windows-dev-center

I'm building Apache thrift compiler on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010.
I got build error as shown below:
[image: flex: can't open src\thrift\thriftl.cc]

I can't find the file thriftl.cc in all folder or any sub-folders.
Below is my thrift folder. Could anyone help me?

[image]

The whole error is :
    PreBuildEvent:
    flex: can't open src\thrift\thriftl.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: The command "flex -o "src\thrift\thriftl.cc" src/thrift/thriftl.ll && bison -y -o "src\thrift\thrifty.cc" --defines="src\thrift\thrifty.hh" src/thrift/thrifty.yy
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.

So how can I do to remove this error and correctly. I have downloaded the flex.exe and set PATH pointing to it.

Added: I also run the flex command in cmd and got the same error.
Please see screen print in red rectangle below.
And I also tried creating an empty thriftl.cc and got the error "flex: could not create", may be neglected.
I presume the "src\thrift\thriftl.cc" should be an output not existing before the flex command.

[image]

Comment: Oops--didn't notice what an old compiler you were using. My apologies--I don't believe vcpkg will work with that old of compiler.

Comment: OK. I'll delete it. It's an attempt.

Comment: It seems that you are using a relative path, not a full path.

Comment: Did you install winflexbison?

Comment: Yes I did after flex command failed. There I got two tool. I didn't use them yet. I presume the flex should work.